# $(a_n)$ decresing sequence, $(-1)^n a_n$ converges, so does $a_n \rightarrow 0$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Is this statement true?

*If $(a_n)$ is a decreasing sequence, and $(-1)^na_n$ converges, so $a_n\rightarrow 0.$*

My intuition say that is true.
The idea is that, for $(-1)^{n}a_n$ the possibilites are:

**1)** $a_n$ is an "decreasing alternanting sequence", like $a_n=(-1)^n\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)$.

**2)** $a_n$ is a decreasing positive sequence that converges to $0.$

Since the first case actually is not a decreasing sequence, the second case is true, and $a_n\rightarrow 0.$

Am I right? If yes, how can I really prove this?

Comment: What does the $(-1)^na_n$ in the title mean?  It is not part of a sentence.  Please make clear the requirement on $a_n$.  $a_n=1+\frac 1n$ is a decreasing sequence, but does not go to zero.

Comment: The statement that I forgot to write is "$(-1)^n a_n$ converges".
Fixed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$(a_n)$ is a decreasing sequence, but you still have to show that it converges to zero.

$b_n = (-1)^n a_n$ converges, so that it is a bounded sequence, which implies that $(a_n)$ is a bounded sequence.

So $(a_n)$ is a decreasing, bounded sequence, and therefore convergent.

Setting $L = \lim_{n\to \infty} a_n$  we have
$$
 b_{2n} = a_{2n} \to L \, , \\
 b_{2n+1} = -a_{2n+1} \to -L
$$
and since $(b_n)$ is assumed to be convergent, $L = -L$ follows, so that necessarily $L=0$.